# Can't attach the event listeners to the dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add some buttons in my document and make them call `getTest()` function. So 1 button should call `getTest(1)`, the 2nd one - `getTest(2)` and so on. But once the script was completed, the event listener is only attached to the last button in the loop.

```
window.onload = function() {
        var button_place = document.getElementById("buttons_here"); // get an element

        /* add the event listeners */
        var i = 0;
        while(i < 10) {
            var cur_i = i + 1;
            var current_but_name = "but_" + (i + 1);
            button_place.innerHTML += "<button class=button id='" + current_but_name + "'>" + cur_i + "</button>\n";
            var bu = document.getElementById(current_but_name);
            //bu.style.color = "#F00";

            bu.addEventListener("click", function() {
                getTest(cur_i);
            });

            ++i;
        }
    }
```

How can I deal with it? How can I attach an event listener to the every button I created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because the loop that attaches is syncronous, finishes and the value of cur_i is always the last value of the iterator when the click occurs. you need to wrap this into a local scope.

```
(function(cur_i){
    bu.addEventListener("click", function() {
        getTest(cur_i);
    });
}(cur_i));
```

this will ensure that the value is correct as of the time of binding.

you really should use `document.createElement` instead and attach the events directly to the element rather than passing through the DOM, which is slower.

---

also, `innerHTML` is immutable and every `+=` you do, recreates the whole lot so on each iteration, you are destroying the old/previous elements and re-adding them but without their event handlers!

Comment: +1. The last part answers the OP's original question but the first part solves another problem in the code.

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped me. I can't understand syntax: what does `(function(x){/*...*/}(x));` means?

Comment: @RomanChehowsky: Its an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).  It basically creates a function and executes it immediately.  As @Dimitar said, it solves the "`cur_i` is always the last value issue" by creating a separate scope for each iteration of the loop.